# Is this a typo in Warner's differentiable manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider the proof [here on page 14](http://books.google.com/books?id=iaeUqc2yQVQC&lpg=PP1&hl=ja&pg=PA14#v=onepage&q&f=false), the line with "Now ...".

The coordinate functions are defined to be $x_i = r_i \circ \varphi$ where $r_i$ are the projections onto the $i$-th component. So shouldn't it be:

$$ (x_i - x_i(m))\circ \varphi^{-1} = (r_i - r_i(m))$$

that is, $\varphi$ and $\varphi^{-1}$ should cancel out?

In case someone can't access the link I include the relevant part of the page here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they shouldn't cancel out. Note that $r_i \colon \mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$, so $r_i(m)$ isn't well-formed.

The point is that $x_i(m)$ is a constant function, $p \mapsto x_i(m)$, so we have

$$(x_i - x_i(m))\circ \varphi^{-1} = x_i\circ \varphi^{-1} - \left[(p\mapsto x_i(m))\circ \varphi^{-1}\right] = r_i - (\xi \mapsto x_i(m)) = r_i - x_i(m),$$

and now we note that $x_i(m) = r_i(\varphi(m))$ and replace the constant by another expression of the same.